# Plotting a 3d sphere in Python and using a jpg "bumpmap"

Tags: python, 3d, geometry

I'm trying to plot a 3d sphere in Python with matplotlib and Mayavi. The function I'm using is *mayavi.mlab.mesh*

I can change the colours of the sphere, but I can't get either to use a jpg file as a colourmap.

How do I colour the surface of a sphere with an image file?